# deploy signature.html to windows mail app microsoft 365

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, signature

Trying to deploy signature.html to windows "default mail app"
Before sending message signature looking fine [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0blK.png)

after saving signature and sent email - the width between text looks more wider
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTxqP.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Email Signature</TITLE>
<META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY>
<div style="mso-element-wrap:none;overflow-x:auto;">
<table style="WIDTH: 400px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" align="right">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; width: 140px; font-weight: bold;" valign="top" dir="ltr">
    <a href="mailto:mail.com" style="text-decoration:none"; valign="top"><span style='color:black; '>name-name</span></a>
    </td>
     <td style="text-align:center; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; width: 120px; font-weight: bold;" valign="top" >
    <a href="mailto:mail.com" style="text-decoration:none";  valign="top"><span style='color:black'; ></span></a></td>
     <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;width: 140px; font-weight: bold;" valign="top" dir="rtl">
    <a href="mailto:mail.com" style="text-decoration:none";  valign="top"><span style='color:black; '>name-name</span></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</div>
<div>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 9.5pt;width: 140px; valign="top" dir="ltr">work</td>
     <td style="text-align:center; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 9.5pt;width: 120px;" valign="top" dir="rtl"></td>
    <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 9.5pt;width: 140px;" valign="top" dir="rtl">work</td>
  </tr>
</div>
<div>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style='text-align:center;  width: 120px;'>
    <a href="tel:phoneNum" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" align="center">
       <span style='font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:windowtext; text-decoration:none; text-underline:none' align="center"> <br>phoneNum</span><br>
<a href="tel:telNum" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">
       <span style='font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:windowtext; text-decoration:none; text-underline:none; text-align=center'>telNum</span>
    </a>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</div>
<div>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3"><hr width=380px height=5px color="black">
</tr>
</div>
  <div>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="height: 60px;" align="center" display: flex;>
    <a href="http://www.website.com/he" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" alt="Banner" width="331" style="max-width:331px; height:auto; border:0;" src="https://online/logo/logo.jpg">
    </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Trying to deploy signature.html

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `<div>`s. They are not right.

Second, try using the width attribute, i.e. `width="400"` (no units) on your outer `<table>` (but prob everywhere else too). Outlook desktop (all versions incl. Windows Mail) often have strange behaviour like not being able to understand `style=` styles.